# Create Custom UIView with XIB

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a custom UIView control (base class of UIView) that has a XIB and outlets in Monotouch and then be able use this control from code and use it in XCode. I'm struggling I think with the different constructors on the class and how to wire things up ? In XCode when I have added it I change the class to the class of my custom view but nothing shows up when it runs.

Whenever I create a custom view and use in XCode or in code nothing from the view seems to show up. I can change the background of the custom view and can see custom view is on the screen but none of the UI view elements that I added to it are showing. Just wondering if there are any examples anywhere for doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm having some trouble understanding a few parts of the question, and I'm still getting up the learning curve for MonoTouch myself, but I'll give it a try. I apologize in advance if I missed the mark.

First of all, I think what you want is to use UIViewController as the base class, not UIView. I learned a lot from looking at the code that MonoDevelop uses in its Universal View Controller template. Right-click on your project name in the list on the left (below the Solution), select Add > New File, then select Universal View Controller as shown below...

[image]

This will create a view controller that works great, and it's easy to follow its source code.

One other thing: I'm probably stating the obvious, but be sure to save any changes to your XIBs in Interface Builder before you switch back to MonoDevelop.